# Using CMfcTabCtrl in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I would like to use MfcTabCtrl in Visual Studio 2013.
In the toolbx, i see the TabCtrl but not the MfcTabCtrl.

How can use CMfcTabCtrl please in vs2013 ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Nixeus

Answer (score 0):

The `CMFCTabCtrl` is usually used inside frame windows.

Inside a dialog I would use `CPropertySheet` and `CPropertyPage`'s. The Tab ctrl there is implicit created. But AFAIK it is possible to subclass it, if you need it...

So the usual way is to use the `CMFCTabCtrl::Create` function. Just look into the samples of the MCF...

Comment: So, i cannot add an MfcTabControl directly from the toolbox ? ( I'm using an application Dialog bases ;-) )

Comment: And? Even than you can reconstruct your application to use a CPropertySheet... What do you expect from a CMFCTabCtrl inside your dialog?