# Using CMFCTabCtrl with a CDialog

Tags: mfc

Someone recently suggested to me to use a [`CMFCTabCtrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfctabctrl-class) in my `CDialog`.

Here is the problem:

[image: Controls]

I am using **Visual Studio 2017** and I can't see the stated control lists. The only one I see listed is **Tab Control**. How am I supposed to use the new version? I want to be able to place this new tab control on my dialog (make it resizable) and add another dialog as the first tab content.

Just can't work out the steps using this newer control since it is not on the IDE.

This is similar question: [Using CMfcTabCtrl in VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746154/using-cmfctabctrl-in-vs2013)

But I am surprised everything must be done manually.

Comment: Usually tab controls are used inside a CMFCPropertySheet. I think that MFC didn't want to lead programmers that are wizard affine on a wrong track. For me: I normally do subclass and control all such special controls by myself.

Comment: @xMRi I have used CPropertySheet and CPropertyPage. All good. I assume there is no real need to use CMFCPropertySheet?

Comment: It is. If you have multiple views or want to have multiple dragable windows inside one. CMFCTabCtrl is used there. Also you might have other window designs were you have a static dialog part above and a variable part below. But this nothing to do with the CPropertySheet.

Comment: @xMRi I have decided to use a `CMFCPropertySheet`. I liked the idea that I could use an outlook style bar. I just had to use `CenterWindow` to center the sheet. All good.